# Elasticsearch find terms from query used for match

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

It seems that an elasticsearch (and Lucene) query would match a part of a field to a part of a query terms. for instance it will match "brown fox" to "quick fox".

Is there a way of extracting terms in original query that Elasticsearch used to perform the matching (in the example above it would be "fox").

Comment: You should look into Elasticsearch's [highlighting](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! If you want, you can register this as an answer for future reference.